# IIS throws Error on loading sub site

Tags: asp.net, iis, umbraco

I have created a sub-site in IIS on top of another running site. So that I can get a URL like `mydomain.com/newsitename`. Everything looked ok to me, But it throws an error

```
    [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'PaymentsModule'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12642964
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12482369
```

When I run the site separately It didn't show any error. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?
Note: Child website is built on Umbraco CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still inheriting the root site Web.config, so you need to override everything not relevant. My guess is the module is added in the root config and you need to remove it in the umbraco one.